# match text followed by multiple line breaks with spaces

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I would like to match a text (numbers, strings, special chars, spaces, one line break ...) followed by at least two line breaks(every line starts with a space then a line break). At the moment I am only able to match the multiple line breaks, but I want to match the text before..
I am using this regular expression: `\n+\s*\n+` this is my input:

```
        Test Test TestTester TestTestt                              Test Test TestTestTestTest: 29724 @erq
        Test Test we                                Test Test, iuow, 0202220
        Test Test  962ert64






                             Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest 
                                      Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest 
                                      Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest 
Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest Test Test TestTestTestTest
```

the output should be :

```
Test Test TestTester TestTestt                              Test Test TestTestTestTest: 29724 @erq
        Test Test we                                Test Test, iuow, 0202220
        Test Test  962ert64
```

Comment: Something like `if (preg_match('~^(.*?)\R{3,}~s', $s, $match)) { echo trim($match[1]); }`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iShVyq/1).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew  but this doe not work for me, as the line breaks after the text always start with a space (See the post, I just have updated it), and I can only use the global flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should help:

```
$re = '/(.+\n)\n\s*\n/sU';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);
```

The flags `s` and `U` are really important here!

`s` means that `.` will match newlines, and `U` will make the quantifiers ungreedy (lazy).

And here is a working example: https://regex101.com/r/G0KS3g/1

**UPD:** If you can't use flags, try this one:

`([\S\s]*?)\n\s*\n`

Here we have a lazy quantifier `*?`, and `[\S\s]` matches any character except a newline `.` OR a newline `\n`.

However, the regex dialect of your software might bring more limitations.

Comment: Can I just have a regular expression with no flags ? or just "global flag"?

Comment: I am not injecting this regular expression in a code, I am using a drag and drop software, that only accepts regular expressions without flags..

Comment: Updated the answer, added an option that doesn't use any flags.

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)*?`, please replace with `.*?`  and add `/s`  modifier.

Comment: I really mean it, never use `(.|\n)`, NEVER.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor! Maybe you can share a Stackoverflow post with a detailed explanation on that?

Comment: Can you please explain why (.|\n) should not be used

Comment: @Mana Discussed it today here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703561/why-using-n-is-a-bad-idea