# Why using (.|\n)*? is a bad idea?

Tags: regex

A few times I saw regex experts say that using `(.|\n)*?` is a really, really bad idea.

Well, I do understand that it's better to replace it with the `.*` and use the `/s` flag. But sometimes the flags are not available, for example, when using regex within a text editor or other software with limited regex functionality. Thus, using something like `(.|\n)*?` might be the only option for multi-line matching.

So, what are the reasons to **always avoid** `(.|\n)*?`?

Comment: Use `[\s\S]` if flags are not available. Or inline modifiers like `(?s)`. You are almost never forced to use an inefficient `(.|\n)*?` that will kill the performance with excessive backtracking.

Comment: So performance is the main reason to avoid `(.|\n)*?`, right?

Comment: @Wiktor The linked duplicate does not answer the OPs question. *Why* is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Tomalak That solves the problem (if there is any). I will find one that is better. The answer is: excessive backtracking. Actually, it is one of the "what does this mean" questions.

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov Compared to `[\s\S]` (or `[\d\D]` or any such x|not-X construct), the `(.|\n)*` is much more wasteful. It's a capturing group, so it needlessly remembers what is being matched, it builds the necessary structures for backtracking that are never really being used, and it matches only one character at a time. This variant is more efficient: `(?:.*\n?)*` but it's way more to write and remember, and `[\s\S]` *still* beats it significantly. Compare how many steps each take on https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Wiktor I'm not sure if "excessive backtracking" is happening. The regex engine goes along the string character-by-character and never really backtracks, as the alternatives in the group always provide a way forward. But it builds everything it needs if it were ever forced to backtrack, which is wasteful.

Comment: @Tomalak  It does backtrack, be the quantifier greedy or non-greedy, that is backtracking.

Comment: If something follows the `(.|\n)*`, it will. Otherwise I would assume it simply keeps alternating until it's at the end of of the string?

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks, it clearly answers my question! Compared the number of steps for the options, got it now.

Comment: @Ildar The second duplicate explains the issue exhaustively, if you haven't seen it being added.

Comment: @Tomalak yes, read and upvoted it already :) Thanks loads for helping to find out!